# SBT - Scala 2.10.4: missing scala.tools.nsc.Global

Tags: scala, sbt, typesafe-activator

I am running ubuntu and installed sbt-0.13.5.  When typing `sbt` on command line I get the following error:

```
Getting Scala 2.10.4 (for sbt)...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 5 already retrieved (0kB/17ms)
Error: Could not retrieve Scala 2.10.4: missing scala.tools.nsc.Global
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deleting `~/.sbt/boot` fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error happen continuously on a jenkins server that was running a sbt related build.

deleting the workspace of the jenkins job and then rerunning the job was what worked for me